# Upgrade pre-release (Daily) Kubuntu 23.04 to full release version

Tags: daily-build

A few weeks ago  I installed a pre-release (daily), pre beta version of Kubuntu Lunar Lobster (23.04) in the belief I would be able to update it to the full release when it was released. Everything runs well, but I note that there are very few updates, and those mainly to themes and apps, not to the underlying O.S.
How do I upgrade to the full release version? - I have noted and tried "sudo do-release-upgrade -d and sudo do-release-upgrade" and similar suggested on this website - however I get "no new release found" and nothing happens. Must I do a whole new install from a fresh download of the iso, or is there some command-line fu that will do the trick? (I'm trying to avoid the full re-install as my machine is a dual boot set-up and the safest way to avoid messing the boot partition is to remove the drive the other O.S. is on - its a NVme drive buried under heat sinks on the motherboard, a major hassle.
If anyone can shed some light on this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Please run the command line `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* |grep -v '^#'` and then edit your original question to add the command and its output. Indent each line 4 spaces to render it as `code`. This will tell us what repositories you may have to remove (or add).

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` (please include output in your question)? I think maybe you're already upgraded to the full version. Is there any specific package you think is not upgraded to the latest version? If yes, please provide info on this.

Comment: You only need to apply all upgrades and you'll find you're running the released *lunar* or 23.04 system.  Do note you'll need to run `sudo apt update` to update software lists (ensure all lines of output are present) then apply all upgrades with `sudo apt full-upgrade`  (note:  `apt upgrade` may not be sufficient as per `man apt`). I'm using what was a *lunar alpha* system, and it upgraded normally.. Post-release I've moved to *mantic* which is when you use the `do-release-upgrade -d` (not to move yourself from *lunar* to 23.04.

Comment: Do note there are cases even on release products that `apt upgrade` isn't sufficient though they are rare... You need to use `apt full-upgrade` far more often especially during the *alpha* stage of a release; but it's also required during *beta* more often than it will when the product is released.  Were you applying all upgrades using `apt full-upgrade` ?  (or `apt-get dist-upgrade`).   FYI:  You can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system non-destructively very easily; especially the *flavors* like Kubuntu